# scl enable access source shell arguments

Tags: bash, shell, redhat

I am activating a scl python environment in a shell script and would like to do some custom installation of virtualenv based on arguments. However, I cannot pass variables from my shell/bash script into the subshell created when I activated the scl environment. How could I access the arguments defined in the shell/bash script?

```
$ARG=argument
scl enable rh-python36 << SS 
echo $ARG
SS
```

For example when I run the above script, output will be:

```
line 1: ARG: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with scl at all, but I can point out some things that're wrong with the shell part of what you're doing:

- Use `$` with variable to *get* their values, not when setting them. Therefore, `$ARG=argument` should be `ARG=argument`. BTW, the error message you gave doesn't actually match this problem; it looks more like what you'd get with spaces around the `=` (e.g. `ARG = argument`), which isn't allowed because it'll treat `ARG` as a command, and "`=`" and "`argument`" as arguments to pass to it. In general, spaces are important delimiters in the shell, and adding or removing them -- even in unimportant-looking places -- can completely change the meaning of a command.
- By default, variables are private to the shell itself. To make the variable available to `scl` (and any other commands you run in the shell), you need to `export` it. Thus, you actually want:

  ```
  export ARG=argument
  ```
- I recommend against using all-caps variable names, since there are a number of all-caps names that have special meanings; using one of those for something else can have weird effects. Lower- and mixed-case variable names are safer.
- Inside a regular here-document (the part that `<< SS` opens), the shell will expand `$variable` expressions before sending the document to the program. If you want that `$` expression to be sent to the program for *it* to interpret, you need to either quote the here-doc delimiter (e.g. `<< "SS"`), or backslash-escape all dollar-signs, backticks, and backslash characters in the document.